# How can I verify subscription payment on In App Purchase on Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Nowadays I'm using a package in_app_purchase 3.0.8 in my app Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

I can make available subscriptions appear and I can even sign a subscription. It turns out that the return is a bool and does not return any information about the purchase, whether it was denied or authorized.
Therefore, I cannot initially verify if the user has already made that purchase and/or is valid.

I looked in several places, but couldn't find anything related.

This part is in the documentation.
This buyNonConsumable function doesn't return any information.

```
final ProductDetails productDetails = ... // Saved earlier from queryProductDetails().
final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
if (_isConsumable(productDetails)) {
  InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
} else {
  InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
}
// From here the purchase flow will be handled by the underlying store.
// Updates will be delivered to the `InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream`.
```

I hope someone can help me with a step-by-step, perhaps, on how to set up checkout. Both for iOS and Android